# Positive solution for an exponential equation

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, roots

Define a function of $t$, $F(t) = e^{X_1t}-e^{X_2t}-e^{X_3t}+e^{X_4t},$ for some fixed real values $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_1<X_2 < X_3 < X_4$. Whether $F(t)$ has at most one positive solution or not.

Comment: Do you mean $F(t)=0$?

Comment: Yes, I mean a root for $F(t) =0$, thanks

Comment: Is $X_1$ > 0$ ?

Comment: $x_1=-0.02, x_2=0, x_3=0.01, x_4=0.02$.

Comment: There is no requirement for the positivity of $X_i$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
f(t) &= \exp(x_1t)-\exp(x_2t)-\exp(x_3t)+\exp(x_4t)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
&x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }
x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4
.
\end{align}

Just one of the suitable examples:

let $x_1=-\tfrac2{100},x_2=0,x_3=\tfrac1{100},x_4=\tfrac2{100}$
and $y=\exp(\tfrac t{100})$.

Then \eqref{1} is equivalent to equation
\begin{align} 
y^{-2}-y^0-y+y^2&=0
,\\
y^4-y^3-y^2+1&=0
,\\
y^3(y-1)-(y+1)(y-1)&=0
,\\
(y-1)(y^3-y-1)&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Ignoring the solution $y=1$, that is, $t=0$,
since $f(0)=0$
is true for any $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{R}$,
the cubic term $y^3-y-1$
in \eqref{2} has only one real root

\begin{align}
y_r&=\tfrac16\sqrt[3]{108+12\sqrt{69}}
+\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{108+12\sqrt{69}}}
,\\
t_r&=100\ln y_r\approx 28.1
.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your examples, I think I have found a proof which I will post it later if I make sure it is correct.